# Downloaded podcasts not being saved on iOS, unavailable when offline

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, podcasts

I'm subscribed to a podcast using the default iOS `Podcasts` app. Whenever I open it and see a new episode I click both `Save Episode` and `Download Episode`. It does download the file but then it still shows the cloud icon in front of it. And if I go to airplane mode, that episode gets grayed out, which essentially means it wasn't downloaded.

I've tried this with several episodes during last month, and the app always behaves in the same way.

So I enabled `Sync Podcasts` and `Automatically include *all* episodes of *all podcasts*` in the iTunes sync settings on my PC and all those missing episodes magically appeared in iTunes on my computes showing as Unplayed - turns out it did save them, it's just it doesn't list them in the iOS app.

I also tried doing this the other way around - downloaded an episode through iTunes on my PC and sync'd the library with the phone, but that episode it downloaded still does not show up on the phone.

Though I do have one saved episode showing on my phone (the first one I saved), it has the cellphone icon in front of it. I did not do anything special, it's just it worked for that one episode and does not work for all others.

My iOS/iTunes settings are:

- limit episodes = off
- download episodes = all unplayed
- delete played episodes = off
- background app refresh = on
- mobile data = on
- sync podcasts = on

I found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147517/why-do-these-podcast-episodes-say-they-are-temporarily-unavailable-even-though-t) but it looks like a different issue because in my case the episodes are not getting saved at all.

It also does not seem to be checking for new episodes every 6 hours and does not issue any push notifications, as per the settings.

Am I missing something? Please help

**UPDATE** I tap "..." and select "Save Episode" and "Download Episode", which it does, but as soon as it finishes downloading, it never saves the file, and if I tap "..." again, it still offers me to download it. So I got really tired of this and deleted the whole podcast feed from my phone, but then it immediately re-appeared with most of those saved episodes marked as unplayed. Well, most, but not all of them - some of the items I can see on iTunes are still unavailable on the phone.

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you by chance also using a non-public URL for your podcast?